# Installation of 2 node cluster of Hadoop

Tags: hadoop

I am trying to set up a two node cluster using HDP (Horton Data Platoform) 2.0 sandbox. I believe we need to use two different VM or physical machines to set up a 2 node cluster. Is it correct?

I set up a HDP sandbox VM and cloned it to create a second VM. I enabled Ambari in sandbox 1 to configure the sandbox2 as the second node in the cluster. But Ambari failed to register the second sandbox. The log file said issues with host name. I tried to modify host-name of second VM with no luck. Has anyone tried this before? If so what will be a simple way of setting up a 2 node cluster of HDP ?

Comment: Are you able to ssh into the second VM from the first one (or vice versa)?

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible that both your virtual machines have NAT (Network Address Translation) enabled, thus, disallowing the two VMs to talk with each other. NAT is usually enabled by default for security purposes in such cases. You can however go ahead and disable it, or find a workaround to allow the VMs to communicate with each other.
You may want to read section 6.3 in http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_nat